# new step on abaqus using python script

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm trying to create a new step using Python.
I have already created a 'Step1' step which results a deformed structure, and now I'm trying to add new results of a new step 'Step2', which should be inserted after 'step1'.
Using this script:

```
odb = openOdb(path='my_odb_path')
newStep=  odb.Step(name='Step2', previous='Step1',domain=TIME)
newFrame = newStep.Frame(incrementNumber=0, frameValue=0.0)
newField = newFrame.FieldOutput(name='...',description='..', type=SCALAR)
newField.addData(position=...,instance=...,labels=...,data=...)
odb.save()
```

The problem is in the statement "previous", the error message is : (keyword error on previous)
Does anyone knows how to solve this problem
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the error message clearly states the issue, *keyword error on previous* because the correct keyword is `previousStepName` not `previous`. Refer to 34.25 in scripting reference guide for more info.